# How to print the value of const void*

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fn(const void *l) {
    // How to print the value of l. The below line is giving error
    cout << "***" << *l;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    int d = 5;

    fn((char *) &d);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

In function 'void fn(const void*)':
Line 8: error: 'const void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Tried Casting as seen below. It didnt not help. Please provide suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fn(const void *l) {
    // How to print the value of l. The below line is giving error
    int *pInt = static_cast<char*>(l);
    cout << *pInt;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    int d = 5;

    fn((char *) &d);
    return 0;
}
```

In function 'void fn(const void*)':
Line 9: error: static_cast from type 'const void*' to type 'char*' casts away constness
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors

Comment: You cannot dereference a pointer to *cv* `void`.

Comment: `void*` can not be dereferenced. It has to be casted into a pointer of concrete type.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
cout << "***" << *(int*)l ;
```

Comment: what if I call it as `fn(new char);`? Isn't that undefined behavior? This is the worst kind of suggestion. Something that leads to the expected behavior, and, for the untrained eye provides a solution. Dangerous.

Comment: What would be the correct way of handling this Luchian?

Answer (score 6):

You want to display value of a **pointer** itself, or value pointed by it? In the first case, simple

```
 cout << p;
```

is sufficient. If you want to achieve the second thing - it is not possible - pointer points to **void**, and it cannot be dereferenced,  because compiler does not know the type of value 'hidden' behind it.

Comment: +1, you are actually answering the question, although OP might not be aware of it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Not unless you interpret the `void` pointer as something.

Put yourself in the function's shoes: I give you a pointer to "something". You don't know what that something is. I tell you to print that something. What do you do?

Answer (score 1):

The standard requires an explicit cast when dereferencing a void pointer.

Not only the compiler itself but also the standard doesn't allow this.